# Script that removes silences off audio files

Tags: audio, scripting

I've been asked to find the actual runtime of a batch of files. Each of these files contains voice and silences (guided meditation type), and I need to find a way to measure the runtime of just the voice.

The manual way of doing this is opening a file, looking at the wave, identifying the silences and removing them so the final duration of the file is the "just voice" runtime. This can take me 3-4 minutes per file, and that's just too much for a batch of 1800 files.

So my question is: is there a way to automatically delete the silent parts? And if so, can it be scripted or automated in any way?

In my studio we work with Sound Forge and ProTools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProTools has this built in, select the region and edit->strip silence.

SoX can do this if you want to set up some scripts without using ProTools([nice blog post](https://digitalcardboard.com/blog/2009/08/25/the-sox-of-silence/))